# How do I pull a list of document names from SharePoint using R

Tags: r, excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I want to use R to pull a list of document names from SharePoint (consider login in). I tried using Power Query and Excel but struggled because the list I want is a folder within many other folders. Power Query was only giving a list of document on the main folder. Is this possible in R or would I have to look for other alternatives?

Please let know if I should expand with an example of the directory.

Comment: My company won't enable it (well, in truth I didn't ask), but there is a package on CRAN called "Microsoft365R" that has some tools for SharePoint.  Since I can't use them I haven't looked too closely at what is possible, but might be a helpful starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to pull a list of document names from SharePoint, you can try to use PowerShell to achieve this.
Please refer this article:
[SharePoint Online: PowerShell to List All Files in a Document Library](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-all-files-in-document-library.html)